# Remove category and tag base from WordPress URLs without a plugin?

Tags: wordpress, categories, permalinks

I would like to remove the category & tag base from WordPress URL. I have come across other posts and solutions which used plugins. I would like to stay away from plugins and have a solution from within functions.php. This would prevent any future plugin updates or WordPress default files from being changed.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

I have tried these solutions so far:

- This htaccess solution did not work: http://mikepayne.co/2011/remove-category-base-from-url/
- These methods also failed: http://www.askapache.com/wordpress/remove-category-wordpress-urls.html

Comment: DId you finally find a good solution to remove the tag base from the url?

Answer (score 73):

If you want to remove `/category/` from the url, follow these two steps:

1. Go to Settings >> Permalinks and select Custom and enter: `/%category%/%postname%/`
2. Next set your Category Base to `.`

Save it and you’ll see your URL changed to this format:
http://yourblog.com/quotes/

(Source: http://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/daily-tip-quick-trick-to-remove-category-from-wordpress-url/)

Comment: The latest version of WP _(v.4, at least in my case)_, doesn't seem to allow `/` to be set for the Category Base. Suggest to use @Robbert's answer instead.

Comment: Pagination breaks when using a page to list the posts tagged as a given category when using this solution (WP 4.4.2, using . as the category base)

Comment: I can confirm that this breaks in 4.6.1 when dealing with pagination.

Comment: To remove the `/./` from links, use this filter:`add_filter( 'term_link', function($termlink){ return str_replace('/./', '/', $termlink); }, 10, 1 );`

Comment: This breaks pagination. You get error 404 when you try navigating to /page/2

Comment: Use [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/311872/110572) to fix pagination.

Comment: This answer does not work as of 2020 for me. You get 404 on your category pages.

Comment: when settings set as said above, and you have an attachment with the same names an category, you cannot use "is_category()", instead WP will output the attachment...

Comment: great,,,,,!!! it helps for my 5.2 wp

Comment: If you're seeing 404 errors after 2020-ish, be sure you are doing both steps in this solution because `/%category%/%postname%/` is now required as custom URL structure for your categories to load properly without the base.

Answer (score 37):

If you use `Yoast SEO` plugin just go to:

```
Search Appearance > Taxonomies > Category URLs.
```

And select `remove` from `Strip the category base (usually /category/) from the category URL`.

Regarding the tag removal I did not found any solution yet.

Comment: As of April 13, 2017 the "dot" method of doing this breaks many features of Wordpress 4.6 and greater. In other words, it's not a viable solution anymore. However, Yoast manages this effortlessly. Install the plugin, enable the feature, and it works flawlessly. Plus you get a great plugin to manage a lot of your site. Win Win!

Comment: Also might add that 'Advanced settings pages' need enabling under the 'Features' tab of the plugin in its current version.

Comment: But the question is how to make it without plugin?

Comment: Yes, but as you can see, there are peoples who reach this page and want to fix this issue even with a plugin, so this answer is helpful for them, that's why they rate it. What do you expect now from me? To delete the answer?

Comment: what about TAG??

Comment: In recent versions (tested version 9) this option now is hidden under `Search Appearance > Taxonomies > Category URLs`.

Comment: Using Yoast or Rank Math for removing Base category creates problem for Elementor page. Once turn off Category Elementor page refer to default Hello template rather than the page you create with Image for Blog, News, Albums or Video gallery Pages

Answer (score 19):

Whilst you dismiss it as a solution, the plugin is by far the easiest and most consistent method and they don't change any WordPress default files.

http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-no-category-base/

It hasn't needed to be updated for a year, so it is not exactly creating any problems with updates.

There is no simple hand rolled solution that will do all of this that does not just replicate what the plugin does from within your own functions.php

- Better and logical permalinks like myblog.com/my-category/ and myblog.com/my-category/my-post/.
- Simple plugin - barely adds any overhead.
- Works out of the box - no setup needed. No need to modify
  WordPress files.
- Doesn't require other plugins to work.
- Compatible with sitemap plugins.
- Works with multiple sub-categories.
- Works with WordPress Multisite.
- Redirects old category permalinks to the new ones (301 redirect, good for SEO).

Plus you get the benefit that if WordPress does change, then the plugin will be updated to work whilst you would then have to figure out how to fix your own code on your own.

Comment: Plugin works well. I'm still interested to see alternate solutions.

Comment: Here's a more up-to-date alternative: [**Remove Category URL**](https://wordpress.org/plugins/remove-category-url/)

Comment: Too many plugins on a site causes problems and makes using version control (like git) with a Wordpress theme difficult. So this would ideally be done without

Comment: this plugin still works as of November 13, 2015. Wordpress 4.3.1

Comment: worked better for me than the accepted solution, which broke category.php template page

Comment: Op asked for an answer "without a plugin"

Comment: plugin doesn't exist anymore

Comment: Not only is this exactly the opposite of an answer to the question, and assumes what is 'easiest', but the link reports `This plugin has been closed and is no longer available for download.`

Answer (score 16):

1. Set Custom Structure: /%postname%/
2. Set Category base: . (dot not /)
3. Save. 100% work correctly.

Comment: This makes category to disapear but if I press on that new link it will redirect me to a none existing page. Why?

Comment: Doesn't work for me either--makes breaks the category links. I bit the bullet and installed the plugin.

Comment: this solution breaks my page and give a me a none existing page

Comment: This works for only post category but with tag, which show 404 after following this guidance!

Comment: This no longer works, you must use `/%category%/%postname%/` as the custom URL structure otherwise the category URLs will 404 error...

Answer (score 5):

instead put this in your functions.php
works fine, no redirect problems.

```
function fix_slash( $string, $type )
{
global $wp_rewrite;
if ( $wp_rewrite->use_trailing_slashes == false )
{
    if ( $type != 'single' && $type != 'category' )
        return trailingslashit( $string );

    if ( $type == 'single' && ( strpos( $string, '.html/' ) !== false ) )
        return trailingslashit( $string );

    if ( $type == 'category' && ( strpos( $string, 'category' ) !== false ) )
    {
        $aa_g = str_replace( "/category/", "/", $string );
        return trailingslashit( $aa_g );
    }
    if ( $type == 'category' )
        return trailingslashit( $string );
}
return $string;
}

add_filter( 'user_trailingslashit', 'fix_slash', 55, 2 );
```

Comment: Great solution **without plugin**! Just what I needed!

Comment: However, the above doesn't seem to work for **sub-categories**, though... eg. `www.site.com/main-category/sub-category/`. Returned a 404 error page

Comment: @Robbert Just why this check is needed?: `if ( $wp_rewrite->use_trailing_slashes == false )........`

Comment: Doesn't do anything for me.

Comment: This doesn't seem to address tags.

Answer (score 3):

The dot trick will likely ruin your rss feeds and/or pagination. These work, though:

```
add_filter('category_rewrite_rules', 'no_category_base_rewrite_rules');
function no_category_base_rewrite_rules($category_rewrite) {
    $category_rewrite=array();
    $categories=get_categories(array('hide_empty'=>false));
    foreach($categories as $category) {
        $category_nicename = $category->slug;
        if ( $category->parent == $category->cat_ID )
            $category->parent = 0;
        elseif ($category->parent != 0 )
            $category_nicename = get_category_parents( $category->parent, false, '/', true ) . $category_nicename;
        $category_rewrite['('.$category_nicename.')/(?:feed/)?(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$'] = 'index.php?category_name=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]';
        $category_rewrite['('.$category_nicename.')/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$'] = 'index.php?category_name=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]';
        $category_rewrite['('.$category_nicename.')/?$'] = 'index.php?category_name=$matches[1]';
    }
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $old_base = $wp_rewrite->get_category_permastruct();
    $old_base = str_replace( '%category%', '(.+)', $old_base );
    $old_base = trim($old_base, '/');
    $category_rewrite[$old_base.'$'] = 'index.php?category_redirect=$matches[1]';
    return $category_rewrite;
}

// remove tag base
add_filter('tag_rewrite_rules', 'no_tag_base_rewrite_rules');
function no_tag_base_rewrite_rules($tag_rewrite) {
    $tag_rewrite=array();
    $tags=get_tags(array('hide_empty'=>false));
    foreach($tags as $tag) {
        $tag_nicename = $tag->slug;
        if ( $tag->parent == $tag->tag_ID )
            $tag->parent = 0;
        elseif ($tag->parent != 0 )
            $tag_nicename = get_tag_parents( $tag->parent, false, '/', true ) . $tag_nicename;
        $tag_rewrite['('.$tag_nicename.')/(?:feed/)?(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$'] = 'index.php?tag=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]';
        $tag_rewrite['('.$tag_nicename.')/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$'] = 'index.php?tag=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]';
        $tag_rewrite['('.$tag_nicename.')/?$'] = 'index.php?tag=$matches[1]';
    }
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $old_base = $wp_rewrite->get_tag_permastruct();
    $old_base = str_replace( '%tag%', '(.+)', $old_base );
    $old_base = trim($old_base, '/');
    $tag_rewrite[$old_base.'$'] = 'index.php?tag_redirect=$matches[1]';
    return $tag_rewrite;
}

// remove author base
add_filter('author_rewrite_rules', 'no_author_base_rewrite_rules');
function no_author_base_rewrite_rules($author_rewrite) { 
    global $wpdb;    
    $author_rewrite = array();    
    $authors = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT user_nicename AS nicename from $wpdb->users");    
    foreach($authors as $author) {
        $author_rewrite["({$author->nicename})/(?:feed/)?(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$"] = 'index.php?author_name=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]';
        $author_rewrite["({$author->nicename})/page/?([0-9]+)/?$"] = 'index.php?author_name=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]';
        $author_rewrite["({$author->nicename})/?$"] = 'index.php?author_name=$matches[1]';
    }      
    return $author_rewrite;}
add_filter('author_link', 'no_author_base', 1000, 2);
function no_author_base($link, $author_id) {
    $link_base = trailingslashit(get_option('home'));
    $link = preg_replace("|^{$link_base}author/|", '', $link);
    return $link_base . $link;
}
```

Comment: Your functions.php file

Comment: It breaks the pagination.

Comment: it breaks the theme, should I add anything else ?

Answer (score 2):

The non-category plugin did not work for me.

For Multisite WordPress the following works:

1. Go to network admin sites;
2. Open site under `\`;
3. Go to settings;
4. Under permalinks structure type `/%category%/%postname%/`.
   This will display your url as `www.domainname.com/categoryname/postname`;
5. Now go to your site dashboard (not network dashboard);
6. Open settings;
7. Open permalink. Do not save (the permalink will show uneditable field as `yourdoamainname/blog/`. Ignore it. If you save now  the work you did in step 4 will be overwritten. This step of opening permalink page but not saving in needed to update the database.

Answer (score 2):

If you're still searching for the combination (tags, categories and pages on the url-base), you can do it like I did.

- Open the settings for permalinks and set a dot (`.`) for the category- and tag-base (https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/removing-category-base-urls-wordpress/)
- Install the plugin [wp-no-tag-base](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-no-tag-base/)

Tested using Wordpress 3.9.1

If you have pages, categories or tags having the same name, the system will take:

1. tag
2. page
3. category

Comment: Plugin no longer available.

Answer (score 1):

https://wordpress.org/plugins/remove-category-url/
Use this plugin it does the job perfectly of hiding the category-base
It does not require any setting just install and activate.

Comment: The question is looking for a solution "without a plugin".

Answer (score 1):

Select Custom Structure in permalinks and add /%category%/%postname%/ after your domain. Adding "/" to the category base doesn't work, you have to add a period/dot. I wrote a tutorial for this here: [remove category from URL tutorial](http://jonnyjordan.com/blog/how-to-remove-category-from-your-urls-in-wordpress/)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for subcategories though. You will get a 404.

Answer (score 1):

I don´t know how to do it using code, but for those who don't mind using a plugin. This is a great one that works for me:

https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/permalink-manager/

Answer (score -1):

## updated answer:

other solution:

In  wp-includes/rewrite.php file, you'll see the code:

`$this->category_structure = $this->front . 'category/';`
just copy whole function, put in your functions.php and hook it. just change the above line with:

`$this->category_structure = $this->front . '/';`

Comment: Is it wise to change files in wp-includes? In case there is an update from WordPress, all changes would be lost. There is a solution mentioned above using functions.php.

Comment: Modifying core files is rarely the solution you're looking for, as these can be modified and overwritten by the core developers at any time.

Comment: Looks like the answer is updated to not modify core files, and just copy it to put in your own functions file.

Answer (score -1):

```
add_action( 'init', 'remove_category_perma' );
function remove_category_perma() {
    unset($GLOBALS['wp_rewrite']->extra_permastructs['category']);
}
```

Comment: FWIW, this does not solve the problem. This entirely disables (as of WP 5.7) "friendly" link URLs on category pages entirely. My category pages after using this just became `?cat=xx`.

Answer (score -1):

**WordPress 5.0.2:**

To remove category slug from existing posts, do this :

1. Navigate to Settings > Permalinks and change Custom Structure from `/%category%/%postname%/` to: `/%postname%/`
2. Keep Category and Tag bases empty (which is the default also)
3. Save

All posts can now be directly accessed via `domain.com/%postname%/` and all categories can be accessed via `domain.com/category/xyz/`. WordPress will automatically add all the 301 redirects for the old urls. So, if someone accesses `domain.com/%category%/%postname%/`, they will automatically get redirected to `domain.com/%postname%/`.

Comment: This does not answer the question; the category pages still use /category/term/ ...

Answer (score -1):

Modifying WP core files doesn't seems to be a solution for removing the category prefix. Also the "." fix via the `Permalinks` doesn't seems to work.

I believe its better to have this set via `Yoast SEO plugin` or `Rank Math SEO Plugin`, hoping almost all WordPress sites have either one of this plugin for SEO purpose.

No complicated steps, just a few mouse clicks and eventually forget about it.

If you are using Yoast SEO Plugin,

`Yoast SEO` > `Search Appearance` > `Taxonomies`

[image]

If you are using Rankmath SEO Plugin,

`Rankmath` > `General Settings` > `Strip Category Base`

[image]

And here is a dedicated plugin that meets the purpose: https://wordpress.org/plugins/remove-category-url/ , if that helps someone.

Comment: "I would like to stay away from plugins and have a solution from within functions.php"

Answer (score -3):

Adding "." or "/" won't work if you want a consolidated blog view.  Also, I have know idea what that solutions would do for the RSS or XML feeds.  I feel better sticking with the WP convention.  However, I did come up with a more elegant approach.

First, I name the base category url "blog"

Then I created a category called "all".  Finally, I but all my subcategories under "all".  So I get a url structure like this.

```
/blog - 404 - recommend 301 redirect to /blog/all/    
/blog/all/ -  all posts combined.
/blog/all/category1/ - posts filtered by category1
/blog/all/category2/ - posts filterer by category2
```

I put a custom label on the menu item called "Blog", but it goes to blog/all.  It would be a good idea to 301 redirect /blog to /blog/all in the .htaccess file to avoid the 404 on /blog.