# Remove category from URl

Tags: wordpress

In my Permalink Settings I set `/%postname%/`.

I want to remove `/category/` from `www.mydomain.com/category/tourism/spa`.

I set Category base `/`. But it works only for parent category.

- `www.mydomain.com/category/tourism` - works but
- `www.mydomain.com/category/tourism/spa` - Page not found.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove category & tag base from WordPress url - without a plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17798815/remove-category-tag-base-from-wordpress-url-without-a-plugin)

Answer (score 1):

By far the easiest solution is to install a plugin like [WP No Category Base](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-no-category-base/) to deal with this for you

This will deal with all the complexities and just work.

Comment: Do not want to use plugin!

Comment: In that case you need to replicate all the functionality from that plugin in your own file