# How to remove tag from url

Tags: wordpress, url, tags

I want remove tag from a url to help with Google for best SEO. For example:

old url:

```
example.com/tag/hello
```

I want it to be:

```
example.com/hello
```

How do I do that in wordpress? And how do I make the url direct from the old url?

I use this code in functions.php:

```
function stf_redirect_to_post(){
    global $wp_query;

    // If there is one post on archive page
    if( is_archive() && $wp_query->post_count == 1 ){
        // Setup post data
        the_post(); 
        // Get permalink
        $post_url = get_permalink();
        // Redirect to post page
        wp_redirect( $post_url );
    }
```

This code makes any url like:

```
http://example.com/tag/sms/
```

to be:

```
http://example.com/special-offers/website-messages/
```

Please help to remove tag.

Comment: You need to change register_taxonomy tags rewrite slug. Or write custom rewrite rule in .htaccess But it might conflict with a page having same rewrite slug as tag. In wordpress website check [Here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks)

Comment: This plugin might help too [Plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-no-category-base/). And here is a solution for Multisite wordpress [Click here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17798815/remove-category-tag-base-from-wordpress-url-without-a-plugin)

Comment: not work for tag :( any help??

Answer (score 1):

I found this plugin to remove the tag from the URL [WP-No-tag-base](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-no-tag-base/)