# WordPress: Same Permalink structure for pages, a custom post type and a taxonomy?

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

Is it possible to have the same permalink structure for pages, a custom post type and a custom taxonomy. The desired permalink for them all is `http://sitename.com/{slug}`

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

You can use plugin custom permalink. By using this plugin you can set url as u want.

http://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-permalinks/

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Yes and No. You can code something up yourself, create some fancy .htaccess rules or use a combination of plugins.

See this post, despite its name, someone does suggest a plugin - I've used the plugin they talk about (wp-no-category-base), it does the job. **Be aware that you could be asking for trouble doing this** (for instance if you try to label a particular post with the same name as the category/custom taxonomy/etc - read the accepted answer here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/42120/remove-slug-in-taxonomy-url):

[Remove category & tag base from WordPress url - without a plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17798815/remove-category-tag-base-from-wordpress-url-without-a-plugin)

I'm fairly sure it handles custom post types - can't remember. If not, check out this:

https://github.com/markoheijnen/wp-no-taxonomy-base

Note: this code has not been updated in a long time.