# Why Wordpress donot remove [category] in the category's URL

Tags: php, wordpress

As all your know, there is a prefix [category] in WordPress category page, and there are many plugins to remove that prefix. WordPress doesn't allow you to have a blank prefix for categories (they insert category/ before the name).

but I wonder why WordPress do not remove that prefix by itself?is there any difficult to do that?
is there any important affect as remove the prefix or not? My English is poor, i hope i have made myself clear.

I do not want to use the following plugin recommended by Yoast

```
The Top Level Categories plugin allows you to remove the prefix before the URL to your category page. For example, instead of http://example.com/category/work, you can use http://example.com/work for the address of "work" category. WordPress doesn't allow you to have a blank prefix for categories (they insert category/ before the name), this plugin works around that restriction.
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a programming question. It is more suited for http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17798815/remove-category-tag-base-from-wordpress-url-without-a-plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change in permalink setting from admin panel for these.
Go to settings/permalinks and add category base '.' for removing '/category' from url.
See the screenhot..[image: Sceenshot]

Comment: It works, but when i open the category page, it shows 404 error.i think the rewrite rules is incorret, and how to rewrite the right write rules for that change?

Comment: For these you need to give permission to your .htaccess file