# WordPress 404 error with pagination /page/2/ when setting posts_per_page

Tags: php, wordpress, function, wordpress-theming, http-status-code-404

I am fairly new to coding with WordPress. Essentially what my intention was is to set different post per page limits for separate categories.

so I edited the functions.php file on my theme with the following code.

```
// Set the posts per category.
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'per_category_basis');
function per_category_basis($query){

    if ($query->is_category) {
        // category named 'books' show 12 posts
        if (is_category('team')){
            $query->set('posts_per_page', 100);
        }

        if (is_category('our-work') || is_category('news')){
            $query->set('posts_per_page', 2);
        }
    }
    return $query;
}
```

this does work perfectly for displaying the number of posts. The problem is when navigating to page 2 **website.com/news/page/2/** I will get a 404 error.

I have already attempted changes to the function.php and searched google for other options. I've changed the settings under reading and still no luck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am aware there is a 7 year old plugin called category pagination fix. but it is out dated and doesn't work with PHP 7.2 and latest version of WordPress.

Comment: Update: also noticing the issue may have something to do with permalink settings:
Currently using /%category%/%postname%/
but when i change to plain URLS like: /?paged=2&cat=3 will work correctly.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29468231/wordpress-category-php-page-pagination-showing-404-page

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so I found out the issue.

The reason why this page was displaying a 404 is because under **settings > permalinks** i was using the custom structure

### /%category%/%postname%/

and had the "category base" set to "." (a fullstop) in term this removed the pages from being **/category/news/page/2** to **/news/page/2** but also broke the pagination..

The easiest fix i found was simply installing the below plugin. Fixed my issue and made pagination work 100% correctly.

There is also a similar function in Yoast SEO pro which may do similar.

**No Category Base (WPML):**
https://wordpress.org/plugins/no-category-base-wpml/

Comment: Thanks, I was having the same issue using "." to remove the category slug, and the plugin fixed the pagination error.