# Content of url A available on url B in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, mod-rewrite

How to make content of this URL:

```
http://www.test.com/category/kariera/
```

available on this URL:

```
http://www.test.com/kariera/
```

in wordpress mod_rewrite?

Comment: There are plugins that will remove the category base from permalinks: https://wordpress.org/plugins/remove-category-url/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove category & tag base from WordPress url - without a plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17798815/remove-category-tag-base-from-wordpress-url-without-a-plugin)

Answer (score 1):

I think you refer to Apache mod_rewrite (wordpress running on apache server),with apache mod_rewrite

Configure your vhost.conf as this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^category/kariera/(.*) http://www.test.com/kariera/$1 [P,R,L]
```

I think I do not forget anything.

- the P means Proxy (the request will be redirected without showing it.
- the R means Redirect (the request will be redirected)
- the L means Last (this one will be the last processed rule for request )

Check [apache.org docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/proxy.html) where they fully explain this.

Hope to help you!!

**EDIT**

Just forgot to tell you that an .htaccess in the original directory with the Rewrite code, will be the same (sorry by my server has multiple vhosts and we do config there)