# Change category page wordpress link

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Is it possible to change the archive page link for category in wordpress from 'mysite.com/category/mycategory' to 'mysite.com/mycategory'.

Answer (score 1):

Use this plugin - [WP No Category Base](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-no-category-base/)

It also redirects your old url to new one.

And its always safe to take a backup before playing with url's.

Or you can [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17798815/remove-category-tag-base-from-wordpress-url-without-a-plugin) for doing it without using a plugin