# Remove Category (page) base for WordPress URL for customized code

Tags: php, wordpress

The most relevant thread I've found in here is this:
[Remove category & tag base from WordPress url - without a plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17798815/remove-category-tag-base-from-wordpress-url-without-a-plugin)

I've tried everything in there - from changing the functions.php file to installing the wp-no-category-base plugin.
After working with this for hours I believe I understand what's the issue (although I don't have the solution).

I added the following code:
https://gist.github.com/morsdyce/9e88db1eba916163cc23

What this code does is pretty straight forward - for every page that I attribute another page to it, it will be considered as a category, plus - it won't be a drop down be have it's own unique lines.

For instance - see the following screen shot:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9Ajq.png)

Still, I would like to remove the category from the URL.
Bear in mind this is **not** the category per se but the page (parent).

Any idea how to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Set your permalinks to /%category%/%postname%/ and then put a period/dot into the Category base form(or just change it to something else). It could help.

Comment: Thanks but I've tried this as well. I'm not sure if it matters, but as I said I'm working with pages only (not posts or categories). Also, if this matters for any other reason - I'm working on a staging site (via IP, the actual domain is not activated yet).

Comment: Perhaps anybody else?