# Removing category base form links messes up the parent-child behavior

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, categories, permalinks

Cross posted from [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/220396/removing-category-base-form-links-messes-up-the-parent-child-behavior) for better visibility.

I am using the 'standard' trick for category removal in wordpress. In my permalinks I set the permalinks structure to

```
/%category%/%postname%/
```

And my category base to

```
.
```

Which worked fine, until the client said he wants parent categories to appear in the header of the article, and the child categories to show in the footer of the articles on the home/index pages...

I've set it up, but the problem is that my child categories links are now:

```
http://www.example.com/./parent_category/child_category
```

And when I click the child category, I get sent to the latest article.

I've tried to add in my `.htaccess`

```
RewriteRule ^category/(.+)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But this did nothing.

Now all this works, when I remove the dot, but then my links look like:

```
http://www.example.com/category/parent_category/child_category
```

And client explicitly doesn't want `category/` in the link...

Other than installing a plugin, what can I do? How to sort this? Can I have

```
http://www.example.com/parent_category/child_category
```

As my permalink, and if so how to achieve this?

**EDIT**

[This plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/remove-category-url/) seems to fix the issue, but it would be great if I didn't need 3rd party plugin for this :\

Comment: Have a look on this ans
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17798815/remove-category-tag-base-from-wordpress-url-without-a-plugin/27569173#27569173

Comment: And the comment said: `However, the above doesn't seem to work for sub-categories, though... eg. www.site.com/main-category/sub-category/. Returned a 404 error page ` So it's a no go solution...

Comment: @dingo_d Did you get the solution? I am also looking for this. :(

Comment: I think I installed some plugin in the end. It was a long time ago so I don't really remember, and these days I'm using nginx...