# Change url of categories

Tags: wordpress, function, wordpress-theming

I created a page listing the categories with this function:

```
function show_categories_fn(){
  return wp_list_categories("echo=0&title_li");
}
add_shortcode('show_categories', 'show_categories_fn');
```

But, when I click the category link, I find the list of posts bound to this one, but the url is `mysite.com/category/mycategory`

Yet, I would like to have only `mysite.com/mycategory`.

Do you know how can it be done?

**Edit :**

I am not sure that this answer answers my question. For my posts I want the structure the url / categoryname / postname, but when I click a category I want only the category (url of archive page), without the sub-folder category which corresponds to nothing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove category & tag base from WordPress url - without a plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17798815/remove-category-tag-base-from-wordpress-url-without-a-plugin)

Comment: I am not sure that this answer answers my question. For my posts I want the structure the url `/ categoryname / postname`, but when I click a category I want only the category (url of archive page), without the sub-folder `category` which corresponds to nothing

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be to instal this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/fv-top-level-cats/

Alternatively, you can set your permalinks to `/%category%/%postname%/` and then put a period/dot into the Category base form.

See this article: https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/removing-category-base-urls-wordpress/