# Remove category in WordPress url

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a WordPress blog with posts that has categories, this could be an example of my url:

```
www.example.it
```

The url for my post is now:

```
www.example.it/sample-post
```

The url for my category list of posts is now:

```
www.example.it/category/my-category
```

I would like my urls like this:

```
wwww.example.it/sample-post (for posts)

www.example.it/my-category (for categories)
```

After googled I founded this solution that I tried:

```
Go to Setting > Permalinks
Select Custom Structure
Add /%category%/%postname%/ after your domain
Change Category Base to period/dot.
```

In this way the category url is correct:

```
www.example.it/my-category
```

but post url is not:

```
www.example/my-category/sample-post
```

What could I change for get the url like I want?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove category & tag base from WordPress url - without a plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17798815/remove-category-tag-base-from-wordpress-url-without-a-plugin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restore the permalink selecting "Post name" and then install this plugin. No configuration needed, it replaces the word "category" in the url of category template.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/no-category-parents/

Answer (score 3):

You don't need PHP to do this, just go to Settings->Permalinks and select "Post name".

If you want to make some custom link structure, please take a look at [Wordpress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks)

Comment: If i select "Post name" my url category will be "www.example.it/category/my-category" instead of "www.example.it/my-category" that is what I really want

Answer (score 0):

Remove `%category%` from your permalink structure and install [Remove Category URL](https://wordpress.org/plugins/remove-category-url/) plugin.

Comment: I tried and it does exactly what I did. It modifies correctly the category url but it modifies also post url (I don't want this)