# .htaccess rewrite rules, cause loop in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm working in this site: 
`http://portugal.dk.linux134.unoeuro-server.com/`

And i'm trying to remove sub directories form the url, like:
`http://portugal.dk.linux134.unoeuro-server.com/artikel/kulturrejser-til-portugal/`

In the URL above I would like to remove `/artikel/` 
So that it would only be the post name visible in the url.

I've tried to edit the permalink in wordpress admin to `/%postname%/` 
But it still gives me the sub directories in the url.

I've also tried this code, shown below, in the .htaccess file and the themes functions.php file. 
But it just causes an infinite loop.

```
RewriteRule ^artikel/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,NC,L]

functions.php
remove_action('template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical');
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What does `artikel` mean, is that a category or somethingelse?

Comment: Yea it's actually just a category.. Could be /lolz/ or /article/ or something totally different :)

Answer (score 0):

Editing the permalink rules is the correct way to bulk change permalinks.

Some things that could be causing you to still see the old permalinks:

- Caching - if you have server-side caching enabled, try clearing this, as well as your own browser cache. I find it helpful to use Webconfs HTTP Header Check to make sure it's not just my own browser.
- Duplicate slugs - if you have a Page that has the same slug as a Post, and you then try to set permalinks to `example.com/postslug`, this will cause a conflict and WordPress may react in odd ways. Make sure you don't have any Pages (or other post types) with the same slugs as any Posts.
- Other plugins - if it's not a live site you may find that deactivating all your plugins identifies one that is also redirecting things or setting category URLs. Less common, but still possible.

You might also try [this Stack solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20911169/7003589) of setting your category base to a period.