# Category page permalink change wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

My permalink at present:
Subcategory pages:
Present  URL:

```
https://<domain>/news/cloud/hybrid/
https://<domain>/news/cloud/private/
```

I want to be some thing like below :

```
https://<domain>/cloud/hybrid/
https://<domain>/cloud/private/
```

I have tried with below filter its not working as per requirement:

```
add_filter( 'post_link', 'remove_parent_cats_from_link', 10, 3 );
function remove_parent_cats_from_link( $permalink, $post, $leavename )
{
    $cats = get_the_category( $post->ID );
    if ( $cats ) {
        usort( $cats, '_usort_terms_by_ID' ); 
        $category = $cats[0]->slug;
        if ( $parent = $cats[0]->parent ) {
            $parentcats = get_category_parents( $parent, false, '/', true );
            $permalink = str_replace( $parentcats, '', $permalink );
        }
    }
    return $permalink;
}
```

Comment: so it will need to work for all url like post products etc should need to show only child category into URL?

Comment: for all we need to remove the news, the news main parent category , for all category, subcategory and post URLs we need to remove the news slug from permalink

Comment: can you show me a screenshot of your permalinks ?

Comment: [link] https://site-url/news/cloud/hybrid/ [/link] this is the url

Comment: url not working:

Comment: not the site-url and next started news/cloud/hybrid/ this is only format for all url sub category

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160054/discussion-between-krishna-and-r-k-bhardwaj).

Answer (score 0):

I found this handy solution which you can use without a plugin. In [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27569173/4511459)

```
function fix_slash( $string, $type ) {
  global $wp_rewrite;
  if ( $wp_rewrite->use_trailing_slashes == false ) {
    if ( $type != 'single' && $type != 'category' )
      return trailingslashit( $string );

    if ( $type == 'single' && ( strpos( $string, '.html/' ) !== false ) )
      return trailingslashit( $string );

    if ( $type == 'category' && ( strpos( $string, 'category' ) !== false ) ){
      $aa_g = str_replace( "/category/", "/", $string );
      return trailingslashit( $aa_g );
    }
    if ( $type == 'category' )
      return trailingslashit( $string );
  }
  return $string;
}

add_filter( 'user_trailingslashit', 'fix_slash', 55, 2 );
```

If you want a plugin for remove category check [here](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-no-category-base/)

Answer (score 0):

Paste this into your functions.php but need to check permalinks too

```
// Remove category base
add_filter('category_link', 'no_category_parents',1000,2);
function no_category_parents($catlink, $category_id) {
    $category = &get_category( $category_id );
    if ( is_wp_error( $category ) )
        return $category;
    $category_nicename = $category->slug;

    $catlink = trailingslashit(get_option( 'home' )) . user_trailingslashit( $category_nicename, 'category' );
    return $catlink;
}
```

Comment: try to add permalink like this : /%category%/%postname%/    https://prnt.sc/hgnwyp