# How to replace /category and /tag with /blog while adding /blog to posts in a WordPress URL without plugins

Tags: wordpress, customization, permalinks

I would like to adjust the permalinks of my wordpress site without using a plugin. I want to get rid of "/category" and "/tag" while adding a prefix "/blog" to all blog related sites (category and tag overview plus posts).

I use several categories including sub-categories as well as tags but no custom post types. For example:

- Category "animals" with sub-categories "dogs", "cats" and a tag "pet-food"
- One post per sub-categorie, each tagged with "pet-food"
- Hosted on www.example.com

For pages I don't need any customization resulting in www.example.com (/page-A).
For posts the following structure would be ideal:

> (1) www.example.com/blog; Showing all three posts
>
> (2) www.example.com/blog/animals; Showing all three posts
>
> (3) www.example.com/blog/animals/dogs; Showing the one post about dogs
>
> (4) www.example.com/blog/animals/dogs/post-about-dogs; Reading the post about dogs
>
> (5) www.example.com/blog/pet-food/; Showing all three posts

I tried so far several approaches. First of all I went to settings -> permalinks and chose the custom permalink option adding

> /blog/%category%/%postname%/

while leaving the category and tag base options untouched. Here everything is working besides that "/category" and "/tag" still show up in cases 2,3 and 5.

By adding a "." into the optional category base the "/category" disappears in case 2 but now the url of case 3 (with and without "/category") isn't working. Case 5 is still unfixed.

By adding "/blog" instead of "." case 2 and 3 will work both without "/category" as intended but now cases 4 and 5 are broken.

I tried several other combinations with also changing the tag base and in none approach every link variation worked. I even tried a couple of times to reset the htaccess file in between different settings with no success.

I already considered [Remove category & tag base from WordPress url - without a plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17798815/remove-category-tag-base-from-wordpress-url-without-a-plugin) and dozens of other sites. But unfortunately no configuration worked for me so far. I even tried to strip of the "/category" with the option provided by Yoast SEO (which is already installed and what can be used if needed) but this resulted into also cutting of "/blog".

Any help is much appreciated - it would be great if you have a solution for this problem!

Comment: I am pretty sure that your solution `/%category%/%postname%/` is what you are looking for, in fact the tag `%category%`  displays the category and the sub-categories of the current post.
please have a look at this link [link](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-include-category-and-subcategory-in-wordpress-urls/)

Comment: Yes, you are right. /%category%/%postname%/ in addition to /blog is able to do a huge part of the job. I got it from the link you mentioned before asking this question. Unfortunately, it will result in www.example.com/blog/CATEGORY/animals/dogs (or /tag). 
Although I found a way to get rid of /category (and /tag), I found no solution to add /body while doing so. In each scenario of settings at least one point isn't working for me..

Comment: ok I see what you mean now, I may found what you are looking for, please have a look at this [page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/7004/tag-in-permalink-not-working) and let me know if it's good.

Comment: I looked at it but I don't think that it's going to help me. But maybe I only lack some knowledge to know how to use it?

Comment: I will have a look at the second solution on that page, I think you need to add those function to your function.php file in your template folder, I suggest you to create a copy of your function.php.

Another solution in my mind would be "hard coding" any page URL through the wordpress interface, in any post you can insert the related URL, there is a field just above the main editor.

Comment: I already tried some things but they haven't worked so far. So thank you for having a look at it!

The hard coding option won't work because you can only change the end slug of the url. And there is no possibility to adjust the appearance of category pages besides the one I'm already using, at least as far as I'm concerned (besides using code ofc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution to this by myself.

1. Go to Dashboard -> Settings -> Permalinks and use the custom permalink structure "/%category%/%postname%/"
2. Change the tag base to "blog" leaving the category base untouched
3. As I said I already had Yoast SEO so I used it to strip the word "category" for category overviews away (Yoast SEO -> Advanced [maybe you have to enable advanced options first] -> permalinks -> choose remove /category
4. As I wanted "/blog" as base for all blog related posts I added the category "blog" as parent to all existing top categories
5. Enjoy!

Issues why this procedure is needed:

1. /blog/%category%/%postname%/ as permalink structure is not working in combination with removing /category - at least if you are using a plugin for that (I tried several). I know that I wanted an approach without plugin but I found no code solution and I used Yoast anyways.
2. You cas set your posts to "/blog/%category%/%postname%/". If you now change the category base to "." you don't have to eliminate the /category anymore. But this resulted into 404 errors while changing the base to "/blog" results into a wrong url structure.

Issues with this approach:

1. Your archives ordered by date will be reachable by example.com/year/ instead of example.com/blog/year

Answer (score 0):

Simple, install YOAST plugin: 
http://prntscr.com/mpcge6

Comment: Writing the steps in textform directly in this post instead of posting it as an image would rule out the possibility of the link going stale. As it currently stands this might be seen as borderline link-only which might become removed.