# WordPress Permalinks add category name to post url

Tags: wordpress

I have two type of posts: Custom Posts and Wordpress regular posts. 
I want url to be like that:

`/category-name/post-name/` for Wordpress Regular Posts and 
`/post-name/` for Custom post.

I was able to achieve needed url for Custom posts:

```
function remove_base_slug( $post_link, $post, $leavename ) {

    if ( 'trip-options' != $post->post_type || 'publish' != $post->post_status ) {
        return $post_link;
    }

    $post_link = str_replace( '/' . $post->post_type . '/', '/', $post_link );

    return $post_link;
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'remove_base_slug', 10, 3 );

function check_parse_request( $query ) {

    if ( ! $query->is_main_query() || 2 != count( $query->query ) || ! isset( $query->query['page'] ) ) {
            return;
        }

        if ( ! empty( $query->query['name'] ) ) {
            $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'trip-options', 'page' ) );
        }
    }
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'check_parse_request' );
```

As for Regular posts, i tried to do that through `WP Dashboard -> Settings -> Permalinks` and set up it as `/%category%/%postname%`. This way it works for regular post, but break my custom posts url.

Is it any way for me to keep desired url structure for both type of posts?

So i need something like:

```
  if (get_post_type() === 'trip-options') {
     /* URL shoud be /post-name/ */
    }
    else {
      /* URL shoud be category/post-name */
    }
```

Comment: Are you want to use wordpress plugin or custom code function on function.php??

Comment: @PriyankaModi  i already started with custom code. So custom code is better option for me..

Answer (score 0):

You can use this plugin to modify permalink for custom post type 
[Custom Post Type Permalinks](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-permalinks/).

Or if you want to go programmatically, you can follow this answered question on [SO](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/161548/change-the-custom-post-type-permalink)

Comment: Plugin doesn't work for me. There's no any options to hide Custom Post base. You can add or edit anything that will be after /base/ but that's it.

Comment: OKay , You dont even need category name for your custom post type

Comment: you can use this plugin, but it will remove entirely base from all post types https://wordpress.org/plugins/remove-category-url/ or you can follow this solution also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17798815/remove-category-tag-base-from-wordpress-url-without-a-plugin

Comment: @Rost. Why that plugin doesn't work for you, I have used it, Any issues from your side?

Comment: My permalinks is set to be `category/post-name` i want to remove caterogory/post just from custom post

Comment: @Rost. You need to remove only category name `category/post-name` will be `post-name`. Have you checked the links I have provided

Comment: Take a look on my updated question. I want something:  `if (post type == custom-post) { //show url without category }, else { // show url with category }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174877/discussion-between-sudharshan-nair-and-rost).

Answer (score 0):

[image]you can do it simply by adding the custom permalink as /%category%/%postname%/

Comment: I'm getting 404 for my custom post.

Comment: But user needs separate links for posts and custom posts. Your method will change links to all post types

Comment: hmmm. ok better you use https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-permalinks/ then as it will help you achieve what you need