# Wordpress delete /category/ tag

Tags: wordpress

I have category sport on my Wordpress site, now it´s

```
example.com/category/sport/
```

I want to have the category on the first place after domain name ->

```
example.com/sport/
```

without /category/

I dont want to use custom permalinks, pages. Any other solution?

How to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove category & tag base from WordPress url - without a plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17798815/remove-category-tag-base-from-wordpress-url-without-a-plugin)

Comment: In that topic i cannot find answer... no one working from that answers, see the topic

Comment: are you asking for a plugin that makes it?

Comment: Yes it can be plugin.

Comment: sorry usually I prefer not using plugins so I can't suggest you one

Comment: and without plugin how can i fix this? Not via permalinks.

Comment: within the answer of the duplicate of this question you can find everything you need. There are solutions with and without plugin...