# Remove /category/ slug from blog category archive url

Tags: php, wordpress, categories, slug

How i can remove /category/ slug from blog archive url?

**Blog url** is
www.mysite.com/blog

**Blog article url** is
www.mysite.com/blog/my-category/article-name

**But category archive url** is
www.mysite.com/blog/category/my-category/article-name

it should be
www.mysite.com/blog/my-category/article-name

Wordpress custom permalink is: www.mysite.com/blog/%category%/%postname%/

How i can have right url without using plugin?

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17798815/remove-category-tag-base-from-wordpress-url-without-a-plugin

Comment: Thanks but i have already read that post and haven't found a solution for my question

Comment: What is my-category?

Comment: @PrathameshRaut is the name of post category

Comment: Answer to you question can be found in here
https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/

Answer (score 0):

If you use SEO plugin like Rank Math or Yoast, you can do it easily. Or, if you want to achieve it without using any plugins, then follow [Remove Category Slug From WordPress URLs Without Plugins](https://bloggerzia.com/remove-category-slug-from-wordpress-urls-without-plugins/)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34492238)