# Removing 'category' slug from wordpress url with a custom category base 'blog'

Tags: wordpress

I have a wordpress website with the following custom structure

```
/blog/%postname%/
```

The category base is untouched, so when clicking on any category on the website gives the following url:

```
domain/blog/category/category-name
```

Similarly on clicking author, the following url:

```
domain/blog/author/author-name
```

How can i remove the 'category' slug from the above category url, while keeping 'blog' slug intact?

I have used Yoast Plugin, Remove category url plugin, added parent category as blog, added code for removing category, setting category base as ., setting category base as blog/. and other solutions that I could find on the web after 3 days of searching.

On using the plugins, Yoast or remove category url, it also removes the 'blog' slug. On removing category from code by adding in the functions.php file, the url does look like the following, but a 404 error returns.

```
domain/blog/category-name
```

Similarly if i change the category base to blog or blog/., then the author urls return 404 error page.

The code i was using for removing category url is from the following page:

```
function remove_category( $string, $type )
{ 
        if ( $type != 'single' && $type == 'category' && ( strpos( $string, 'category' ) !== false ) )
        {
            $url_without_category = str_replace( "/category/", "/", $string );
            return trailingslashit( $url_without_category );
        }
    return $string;
}

add_filter( 'user_trailingslashit', 'remove_category', 100, 2);
```

Comment: Have you gone into the permalinks settings in wordpress and selecting custom and entering "/blog/%postname%/" then click save settings. Then you need to click save settings again to flush the rules to avoid the 404s. Ensure category base is empty. works fine for me.

Comment: Yes have tried this, but in my requirement, we need to remove the 'category' slug from category url and keep the 'blog' slug intact in the url. On doing the above as mentioned, it doesn't remove the category slug rather the url turns out like:

domain/blog/category/category-name

Comment: Mine returns: domain/blog/post-name. Is "category" a parent category of "category-name"? as perhaps I don't understand your question.

Comment: yes in case of post it returns correctly as you mentioned. domain/blog/post-name but when clicking on category it returns incorrectly as domain/blog/category/category-name

Comment: Nope the category is itself parent category.

Comment: Then that's also weird as when I click a blog category it returns: /blog/plumbing/ where plumbing is the category name. Try disabling plugins to see if issue continues, if so try changing theme, and see if issue continues and let me know.

Comment: Disabled all plugins, and changed theme as well, but still category urls shows as domain/blog/category/category-name. Keeping category base as empty and /blog/%postname% in custom strucutre. Are you using any specific settings for category base or in htaccess file or any custom code?

Comment: Fresh WordPress install with default htaccess so strange

Comment: Just tested with fresh wordpress install, it is showing the category slug. Following url shows on clicking uncategorized category.
localhost/wordpress/blog/category/uncategorized

Comment: Install yoast and in Search Appearance > Taxonomies scroll to bottom and toggle off the categories in URLs maybe?

Comment: Tried that as well, this removes the full url, from the domain till the category name. like domain/blog/category/category-name becomes domain/category-name, whereas we need the 'blog' slug. Basically yoast is unable to differentiate that blog isn't part of category.

Comment: Hmm I’m out of ideas then, did you try the function which gave you the right output and then saving permalinks to refresh rewrite rules? As I don’t think you did that initially

Comment: @OmerKahoot did you solve the isssue?

Comment: @Kiwop, No I wasn't able to resolve it, had to discuss with the client to change the business requirement somewhat which is supportable.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17798815/remove-category-tag-base-from-wordpress-url-without-a-plugin