# How to disable Default Post Category in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm creating a new post without selecting category but whenever new post is created at that time it automatically selects category. I want to disable auto select category.

[image]

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every single post created in Wordpress will be assigned to a category by default. Even if you don't create categories, Posts will be assigned to a default category called "Uncategorized". This is how the Wordpress system works.

First of all, can you explain to us why you don't want to assign categories?

is this because you don't want the category slug added to the post URL? If this is the reason, there are so few ways to achieve this.

This plugin removes the CATEGORY slug from the post URL.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/remove-category-url/

Few other references to removing Category slug from URL without plugins:

https://jonnyjordan.com/blog/how-to-remove-category-from-your-urls-in-wordpress/

[Remove category & tag base from WordPress url - without a plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17798815/remove-category-tag-base-from-wordpress-url-without-a-plugin)

Wordpress post will have 1 CATEGORY. This is how Wordpress works. Maybe if you want to remove the default category but if you want to select a category manually then we can achieve that with some custom coding. But you cannot have a WordPress post without assigning a category to it.

The below code will remove the default category when another category is set to a post. Make sure you have set the default category as Uncategorized.

```
//remove default category (uncategorized) when another category has been set
function remove_default_category($ID, $post) {

    //get all categories for the post
    $categories = wp_get_object_terms($ID, 'category');

    //if there is more than one category set, check to see if one of them is the default
    if (count($categories) > 1) { 
        foreach ($categories as $key => $category) {
            //if category is the default, then remove it
            if ($category->name == "Uncategorized") {
                wp_remove_object_terms($ID, 'uncategorized', 'category');
            }
        }
    }
}
//hook in to the publsh_post action to run when a post is published
add_action('publish_post', 'remove_default_category', 10, 2);
```

Do let me know if this helps.

Comment: I don't want remove slug but I want remove any default category.

Comment: May I know the reason why you want to remove any default category?

Comment: Because I don't want

Comment: Wordpress post will have 1 CATEGORY. This is how Wordpress works. Maybe if you want to remove the default category but if you want to select a category manually then there is option for that. You cannot have a WordPress post without assigning a category to it.

Comment: I want to remove default category,  because I need to have posts without category, because I have a script that lists the categories, and posts inside that categories, and I want to have posts that are not listed in any categories, ho to do this?

Comment: I have the same question.. I have other taxonomies set up too, they don't have a default category.. why should the category taxonomy be so special ?

Answer (score 5):

The best way of removing default category is to change a parameter is to change the parameter '**default_category**' in your '**wp_options**' table.

Set the parameter '**default_category**' to **0**. Note that it won't change the category displayed in your dashboard in the Writing settings, but it will prevent Wordpress to set a default term to your post.

Wordpress doesn't require a term or category to be set by default. It's just not true ;)

Comment: Note that this trick, setting the parameter 'default_category' to 0 will let you delete Uncategorized category if it bothers you.