# How to remove /tag/ from WordPress url ( without a plugin! )

Tags: php, wordpress, tags, wordpress-theming

I need to remove /category/  **and /tag/**  from the urls of my new WP website.
I already found a great and working snippet to remove the /category/ (which I placed inside the functions.php).

But I found no working solution to remove the tag as well.

What I tried so far (aside from YOAST settings, permalink changes etc etc) is this piece of code:

```
function twr_remove_tag( $string, $type )  {           
    if ( $type != 'single' && $type == 'category' && ( strpos( $string, 'tag' ) !== false ) ) {              
        $url_without_tag = str_replace( "/tag/", "/", $string );
        return trailingslashit( $url_without_tag );          
    }      
    return $string;  
}     
add_filter( 'user_trailingslashit', 'twr_remove_tag', 100, 2);
```

This is more or less the same code for removing the /category/ and I think that's pretty close. Maybe just the $type parameter is wrong? What do I have to use here?

Comment: Look for the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17798815/remove-category-tag-base-from-wordpress-url-without-a-plugin

Comment: Yay, saw that before. But it only has a final solution for category, not for tag

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the below code -

```
function fix_slash( $string, $type )
{
global $wp_rewrite;
if ( $wp_rewrite->use_trailing_slashes == false )
{
    if ( $type != 'single' && $type != 'category' )
        return trailingslashit( $string );

    if ( $type == 'single' && ( strpos( $string, '.html/' ) !== false ) )
        return trailingslashit( $string );

    if ( $type == 'category' && ( strpos( $string, 'category' ) !== false ) )
    {
        $aa_g = str_replace( "/category/", "/", $string );
        return trailingslashit( $aa_g );
    }
    if ( $type == 'category' )
        return trailingslashit( $string );
}
return $string;
}

add_filter( 'user_trailingslashit', 'fix_slash', 55, 2 );
```

Comment: Unfortunatly this code works for /category, but not for /tag on my side

Comment: Try to replace "category" with the "tag". then it will work for the tags.