# Prefixing WordPress permalinks with blog and category name

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I am really struggling with WordPress permalinks and wondering if what I'm trying to do is not possible.

I would like the following permalink structure:

- `domain.com/blog/` <-- blog index
- `domain.com/blog/politics/` <-- blog category
- `domain.com/blog/politics/who-is-donald-trump` <-- blog post

The closest I am able to get is:

- `domain.com/blog/` <-- blog index
- `domain.com/blog/category/politics/` <-- blog category (note the addition of the word "category")
- `domain.com/blog/politics/who-is-donald-trump` <-- blog post

For my **permalink structure** I have it set to: `/blog/%category%/%postname%/`

And for my **category prefix** I have it set to: `blog`

This does actually generate the permalinks in the desired format, however the final posts page doesn't work, and returns a 404 error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove category and tag base from WordPress URLs without a plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17798815/remove-category-and-tag-base-from-wordpress-urls-without-a-plugin)

Comment: This question is asked quite a bit, but you'll need to use a plugin, or alter your `.htaccess`. I'm not sure I've ever seen it work correctly - since `/blog` is the base URL for the posts, so anything after that will 404 if there isn't a post with a slug that matches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got this working as follows:

**Permalink structure** set to: `/blog/%category%/%postname%/`

**Category base** set to: `blog/.` (note the period on the end)

This was all fine but in my Yoast post sitemap the URL's contained a period, which was fixed with the following code placed in my theme's `functions.php` file:

```
add_filter( 'category_link', function( $term_link, $term_id ) {
    $term_link = home_url('/blog/'. get_term( $term_id )->slug .'/');
    return $term_link; 
}, 10, 2 );
```